# Join BIGINT to VARCHAR, where VARCHAR contains only a small number of non-numeric characters

Tags: sql, t-sql, netezza

I'm trying to join two fact tables in a Netezza DB on a common acct_nbr field. In table a, it's BIGINT, and in table b it's coded as VARCHAR. (I have no control over the table design, and I suspect it's set up as VARCHAR because it's populated by web input, and needs to be able to tolerate typos.) I'd like to disregard the alpha characters for the join - I'm willing to rule out all fields in table b that contain non-numeric characters. (The field also contains -,?,!, etc.)

I've tried the following:

1. A basic join. Throws Bad int8 representation for '9999R99999', I assume based on the first non-convertible VARCHAR entry it comes across.
2. Using cast/convert on both fields (to BIGINT for b.acct_nbr, to VARCHAR for a.acct_nbr) which I may have implemented incorrectly. Various errors, no results.
3. Using "select ... from table_a a join table_b b on (a.acct_nbr=b.acct_nbr and b.acct_nbr not like '%[^0-9]%')". I don't seem to be able to make this work, and I haven't found a good explanation for how the '%[]%' syntax works. I know what % does, but I've a poor understanding of how to use the carat and the brackets.

I'm sure this is a simple problem, but I'm banging my head against the wall. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Show some relevant sample data,how random are the characters in that varchar?at the beginning at the end,all over the place etc.

Comment: All over the place, for ~ 1 in 1000 records. The most common types are '11111A111111', '111-111-1111', and '111?111111111'.

Answer (score 1):

You can complete the join a few different ways.

```
    select ... 
    from table_a a join 
    table_b b on (a.acct_nbr=b.acct_nbr 
and translate(b.acct_nbr,'1234567890','') in ('','.','-','-.')
```

Or if you have the sql functions toolkit installed you could do this.

```
    select ... 
        from table_a a join 
        table_b b on 
(a.acct_nbr=sql_functions..regexp_extract(b.acct_nbr,'^[0-9]{1,18}')
```